# Summarize result and display the minimum date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have several by number of dates and against them quantity.
the goal is to total the quantity and show only the minimum date

```
   date       quantity
    
  13-SEP-15     5
  16-FEB-20     6
  16-FEB-21     100

  expected result;
          date          quantity
          13-SEP-15       111
```

Comment: SELECT  SUM(quantity) AS quantity, MIN(date) AS MinDate
FROM Orders
GROUP BY date;

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html#GUID-62BE676B-AF18-4E63-BD14-25206FEA0848

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure that the date column's name is `date`?

Comment: this is just an example

Comment: then **what** doesn't work?

Comment: refers to the first comment

Comment: Please be more specific as converting the current one to [a minimal and reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which has sample data along with tried SQL statement(s). Btw, `date` is a reserved keyword and cannot be a column name for a table.

Comment: Use `SUM`, `MIN` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: If you only want a single row the the query in the first comment should not have a `group by` clause - you'll get one result per date with it. Apart from that, do you get the wrong answer, or an error? "doesn't work" isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just two aggregates, nothing else.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (datum, quantity) as
  2    (select date '2015-09-13',   5 from dual union all
  3     select date '2020-02-16',   6 from dual union all
  4     select date '2021-02-16', 100 from dual
  5    )
```

Query:

```
  6  select min(datum) min_datum,
  7         sum(quantity) total
  8  from test;

MIN_DATUM      TOTAL
--------- ----------
13-SEP-15        111

SQL>
```